# How do I tell if my laptop has been messed around with?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, forensics

I just have my laptop to h local service people, but the thing is, I live in a bad neighborhood. I took a backup before giving it. But how will I be able to tell if they switched out any parts with other cheaper parts and stuff like that?

My laptop runs Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 8.1 dual boot.

Comment: Get a receipt from the computer shop.

Comment: Did your computer have high end components in it to begin with?

Comment: You can't, unless you know exactly what was in it **before** you had it serviced.

Comment: Typically, only a few laptop components are generic and removable.  If it still works and shows the same size hard drive and same amount of RAM, it's unlikely anything was swapped or removed that doesn't show up on a receipt.  It wouldn't be worth the time and effort to replace a working used part with another working used or cheap part.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do not let anyone service your computer that you dont trust.

When it comes to laptops, there are very few parts that can be removed.  Generally speaking, the only things that can be removed on a laptop are the memory, hard drive, and optical drives.  Some laptops will come with other removable hardware such as mini-PCI devices, like modems, GPUs, etc, etc.

Did you keep the original documentation from when you purchased the laptop, as that should contain all the hardware that was shipped with the laptop.

You can make a list of your hardware by opening up the `Device Manager` in Windows, expand all the components and take a screen capture.

Also, open `System Information` from the Start menu and you can print out even more information about the computer.